# Validation using an external function in Joi (Node.js)

Tags: node.js, validation, joi

I'm using Joi for validation in my Node.js Rest API. I have a function to validate a specific document and I'd like to know if it's possible to include that function in Joi's validation.

Example:

```
function validateDocument (document) {
    return someCalculation;
}

const schema = Joi.object({
    document: Joi.string().required().valid(validateDocument) // I want something like that
});

const { error, value } = schema.validate(something);
```

Answer (score 2):

Yes. You can use [Joi extension](https://hapi.dev/family/joi/?v=15.1.1#extendextension) to call external function for validation. An example format is given below:

```
const customSchema = Joi.extend(joi => ({
    base: joi.string(),
    name: 'customValidation',
    rules: [
        {
            name: 'validate',
            validate(params, value, state, options) {
                // call custom function and return the result
                // for instance:
                return validateDocument(value);
            },
        },
    ],
}));
```